# Can I monitor contract attributes without sync the whole block?

Tags: go-ethereum

I deployed a contract in my private ethereum network using *geth*.

Now I am only intrested in `some specific atrributes` of this contract,

can I only monitor these values without downloading the whole latest block?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll have to download the whole block. You could use a block explorer to locate specific transactions. But the problem with that is that the block explorer depends on a full node.

If you're trying to monitor transaction to a specific address that might be doable, but imagine a situation where multiple updates may have changed your target attribute within a single block and you won't know which occurred first without full block data.

Comment: I just read the LES protocol (https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-%28LES%29), could you please tell that what is included in the 'ContractCodes' reply ? Can it be used or modified to satisfy my demand? Thx.

Comment: Why don't you just put a getter method in the contract to get/monitor values of attribute?

Comment: Yes, I have a getter method in my contract. But in order to call this view function, I have to download the latest block, and it might include other attribute and other contract data. Is it right? If yes, I want to know a method that can only transfer the specific data.

Comment: You can connect to a remote node and call your contract's getter from it. This is how MetaMask works: It connects to a trusted remote node (infura). This avoids the need to run a client locally.